# O controlo remoto pode ser com ou sem fios?

Tags: português-europeu

Vi a [definição desta palavra na Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/controlo#controlo%20remoto) e fiquei confusa.

O controlo remoto pode ser tanto com como sem fios, ou é exclusivamente sem fios?

Porque tecnicamente o controlo com fios controla "à distância" também, só que está preso por um cabo ou embutido numa parede.

Pergunto isto no contexto de manuais técnicos.

Comment: Olá Catarina, bem vinda. Fiz uma edição à pergunta que tenta torná-la mais clara. (E tirei os obrigados, que aqui não são precisos.) Podes ver as alterações no [histórico da pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/posts/8001/revisions), e reverter para a versão anterior se a preferires.

Comment: É uma pergunta sobre língua portuguesa?   Acredito ser mais apropriada para o site https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Centaurus Sim, neste caso é de língua, gostava de saber isto porque estou a traduzir um manual técnico e queria ter a certeza do termo.

Comment: @CatarinaVieira   Discordo, trata-se de uma pergunta sobre eletrônica.  Mesmo que você esteja a traduzir um manual, a pergunta será melhor respondida por um engenheiro eletrônico.  O melhor conhecedor da língua portuguesa pode no máximo dar uma opinião. Se ele quiser ter certeza, terá que fazer o que você poderia ter feito: consultar um especialista.  .

Answer (score 3):

Normalmente, sem fios.
Mas pode ser ambos.

Normalmente, no contexto doméstico e pessoal, o controlo remoto é sem fios e usa comunicação aérea por ondas rádio ou infravermelhos.

Mas por exemplo no contexto do trabalho submarino, existem operações remotas que são ligadas por fios:

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ve%C3%ADculo_submarino_operado_remotamente

---

Debaixo de água, comunicação acústica ou por rádio é muito difícil. Para trabalhar a grandes profundidades, seria preciso um emissor local (perto do fundo) ou, que é o usado, um cabo umbilical que liga o robot aos controlos no barco.

O cabo umbilical liga fisicamente o robot de trabalho ao barco de onde ele é pilotado.
Leva sinais de controlo e energia para baixo, e traz sinal de vídeo e de sensores (orientação, profundidade, etc) para cima.
Do barco, o piloto controla **remotamente** o robot.

Comment: Já houve um tempo, no fim dos anos 70, em que aparelhos televisores possuíam "controle remoto", porém, dotados de fios. Mas, de fato, eram remotos, pois, o usuário poderia trocar os canais do televisor sem se levantar do sofá.

Comment: Vale lembrar que o "nome completo" do objeto pode ser "_aparelho_ de controle remoto", ou seja, se permitir o controle à distância e for um aparelho distinto o bastante do principal, o termo pode ser usado. No [verbete](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlo_remoto) da Wikipedia também se consideram aparelhos com fios como "remotos".